# Как сделать чтобы скрытый блок появлялся?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Необходимо что бы при клике по img2, вместо block-1 появлялся скрытый блок block-5. Нужен совет или реальная помощь, ибо голова уже вообще не варит. Спасибо.[jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/martynuk/m2z1c76f/5/)

```
<div class="wrapp">
<div class="block-1">
    <a class="img1" href="#"><img src="img1.jpg" alt="img1"></a>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia error vero voluptatibus optio qui ea eaque, delectus ad velit tenetur deleniti eum quia fugiat, magni recusandae esse, enim atque nam?</p>
</div>
<div class="block-2">
    <a class="img2" href="#"><img src="img2.jpg" alt="img2"></a>
    <h2>Ipsum dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam inventore modi dolorum voluptatum tempore consequatur molestiae id optio expedita aliquid amet, praesentium excepturi quod</p>
</div>
<div class="block-3">
    <a href="#"><img src="img.jpg" alt="img3"></a>
    <h2>Consectetur</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi quia asperiores sint, rem minus esse rerum ullam expedita exercitationem voluptates culpa soluta quidem atque neque cumque inventore at dicta aperiam.</p>
</div>
<div class="block-4">
    <a href="#"><img src="img.jpg" alt="img4"></a>
    <h2>Repellat dolore</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat dolore temporibus enim perferendis modi officia soluta, quis, optio voluptatibus dolorum vitae in dolor obcaecati vel laborum facere, ea doloribus asperiores!</p>
</div>
```

```
.wrapp{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
   .block-1, .block-2, .block-3, .block-4{
     width: 43%;
     border: 1px solid red;
     display: inline-block;
     height: auto;
     margin: 10px 3% 10px 0;
     padding: 0 10px;
 }
   .block-2{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
 .block-3{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
 .block-4{
   border: 1px solid yellow;
}
 h2{
   text-align: center;
}


  /*скрытый блок
  .block-5{
   width: 43%;
   border: 1px solid black;
   display: inline-block;
   height: auto;
   margin: 10px 3% 10px 0;
   padding: 0 10px;
 }*/
```

jQuery:

```
 $('.img2').click({
  $('.block-1').hide();
  $('.block-5').show();
 });
```

Comment: где у вас в html части `.img2`? по чему мы должны кликать?

Comment: сорри не тот код кинул, сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А где у вас class `img2` и, собственно, `block-2`? Вот с поправленным вариантом:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".img2").on("click", function(){
        if ($('.block-1').css("display") == "inline-block") {    
            $('.block-1').hide();
            $('.block-5').css("display", "inline-block");
        } else {
            $('.block-5').hide();
            $('.block-1').css("display", "inline-block");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.wrapp{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.block-1, .block-2, .block-3, .block-4{
    width: 43%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px 3% 10px 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.block-2{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.block-3{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.block-4{
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
h2{
    text-align: center;
}



.block-5 {
    width: 43%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px 3% 10px 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
    <div class="block-1">
        <a href="#"><img src="img.jpg" alt="img1"></a>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia error vero voluptatibus optio qui ea eaque, delectus ad velit tenetur deleniti eum quia fugiat, magni recusandae esse, enim atque nam?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-5">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-0Q3kCnPUmdw/UzBjhXx60yI/AAAAAAABk3k/SkhejnRSiD4/s1600/Emoticons%20Sonrientes%2010.jpg" alt="img5"></a>
        <h2>Repellat dolore</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat dolore temporibus enim perferendis modi officia soluta, quis, optio voluptatibus dolorum vitae in dolor obcaecati vel laborum facere, ea doloribus asperiores!</p>
    <div class="block-2">
        <a href="#"><img class="img2" src="http://liubavyshka.ru/_ph/104/2/900525914.png" alt="img2"></a>
        <h2>Ipsum dolor</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam inventore modi dolorum voluptatum tempore consequatur molestiae id optio expedita aliquid amet, praesentium excepturi quod</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="img.jpg" alt="img3"></a>
        <h2>Consectetur</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi quia asperiores sint, rem minus esse rerum ullam expedita exercitationem voluptates culpa soluta quidem atque neque cumque inventore at dicta aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="img.jpg" alt="img4"></a>
        <h2>Repellat dolore</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat dolore temporibus enim perferendis modi officia soluta, quis, optio voluptatibus dolorum vitae in dolor obcaecati vel laborum facere, ea doloribus asperiores!</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: нужно чтобы скрытый block-5 становился на место block-1, а сейчас второй вместо первого

Comment: Поставьте block-5 после block-1. Он всё равно скрытый и не будет отображаться в разметке. Или вам принципиально, что бы он из конца перемещался в начало?

Comment: нет не принципиально, но если сделать так как вы говорите, то второй падает вниз, а должен оставаться на месте...

Comment: блоки не должны менять свои места, клик по второму блоку открывает содержимое второго блока полное (такая задумка)

Comment: Попробуйте его теперь. Изменил html и js

Comment: да теперь работает как надо, спс, а обратно, что бы при клике скрывался 5 блок и становился первый?

Comment: При клике на картинку проверяйте по условию скрыт первый блок (или пятый) или нет и тогда отображаете пятый (или первый).

Comment: уже разобрался, спс